# Delete CSV row for matching record

Tags: php, csv, row

I need to match id's of the array and the row id of the CSV file,if matched then remove that particular row from the CSV file else the file data will remain unchanged.

Here is the code:

```php
if (($handle = fopen("$filename_with_path", "w")) !== FALSE)                
{                                                                              
    while (($data[1] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)                 
    {                                                                          

        if(in_array($data[1],$del_tag_array)){                                 
            unset($data);                                                      

        }   else {                                                             
            $tag_data_from_csv[]=$data;                                        
        }                                                                      

    }                                                                          
    fclose($handle);                                                           
}                                                                              
foreach ($tag_data_from_csv as $data_at_each_index)                            
{                                                                              
    fputcsv($file_pointer, $data_at_each_index) or die('cannot write file');
}
```

CSV file record :

row1 = `1,714,pictures,222`
row2 = `1,713,unique,222`

if 713 = 713,then row with 713 should be deleted from CSV

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php                                                              
<?php                                                                           
$filename_with_path = '/tmp/input.csv';                                         
$del_tag_array = [713];                                                         
$tag_data_from_csv = [];                                                        

if ($handle = fopen($filename_with_path, "r")) {                                
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {                               
        if (in_array($data[1], $del_tag_array)){                                
            continue;                                                           
        }                                                                       
        $tag_data_from_csv[] = $data;                                           
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               
fclose($handle);                                                                
if ($handle = fopen($filename_with_path, "w")) {                                
    foreach ($tag_data_from_csv as $data_at_each_index)                         
    {                                                                           
        fputcsv($handle, $data_at_each_index) or die('cannot write file');         
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               
fclose($handle);
```

The tricky parts were:

- the mode, how you are opening the file handle: see the table for
  [mode here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters). (By opening with `'w'` you just erase it so there are no lines to read)
- you put all the line in csv into one index of data array, making it
  multilevel array instead of just retrieving a value on certain
  position
- undefined handle for writing and array with keys to skip